# Trying to RegExp an array, getting an Uncaught TypeError: x is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to get the file names from an array of S3 presigned URLs. The code looks like this:

```
const input_uri = ["https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/link.link2.website.com/link-file/item-file/item_id%3D168cc901-41fe-4994-a5dd-fbcc7bf1d649/date%3D2021-10-01/item-file-test%20%282%29.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATIQ7FVSIUGCQZL7N%2F20220106%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220106T072037Z&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD8zcE7Dk0NBD2F%2Fr9hyTzZop0%2BeJ%2BnQAthpBO3OaGR7AIgI03YGJOTcNzQ79JjZYQvI4HD4A8hKNC5Edq%2FSXiMZTEqugIIoP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjQ0NNpe7sy2dtEb%2BtoeBydBYt%2B5PfH6o1ISCeGe6WfuUaFQZEM0Yl2AUGhGb06S8dTDEsNqOBjqaAadtJx31fGUhIHkaE21M%2BJffVKmz9XXYeGx2MmpllUzCUbD7vEBM%2BKxJs5XQ%2BiZs5sslLFdfjMaWbrFYgUmMLX6fz4HXABR6zFIBH%2FiIvtijgX4dkXHUWssRHZD96Qo2ATHWVhM%2FxW4ut1LkLJt1c9U44L9eofZ2Zwp5vLyEIem6c2Nmwx0eo4uc2G%2Bk5CTMF8WfWYRMYPHpksM%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=&X-Amz-Signature=2395e814f4d8daa5ae86f9b40b76c16f042757008c595fc1c","https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/link.link2.website.com/link-file/item-file/item_id%3D168cc901-41fe-4994-a5dd-fbcc7bf1d649/date%3D2021-10-01/item-file-test%20%282%29.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATIQ7FVSIUGCQZL7N%2F20220106%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220106T072037Z&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD8zcE7Dk0NBD2F%2Fr9hyTzZop0%2BeJ%2BnQAthpBO3OaGR7AIgI03YGJOTcNzQ79JjZYQvI4HD4A8hKNC5Edq%2FSXiMZTEqugIIoP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjQ0NNpe7sy2dtEb%2BtoeBydBYt%2B5PfH6o1ISCeGe6WfuUaFQZEM0Yl2AUGhGb06S8dTDEsNqOBjqaAadtJx31fGUhIHkaE21M%2BJffVKmz9XXYeGx2MmpllUzCUbD7vEBM%2BKxJs5XQ%2BiZs5sslLFdfjMaWbrFYgUmMLX6fz4HXABR6zFIBH%2FiIvtijgX4dkXHUWssRHZD96Qo2ATHWVhM%2FxW4ut1LkLJt1c9U44L9eofZ2Zwp5vLyEIem6c2Nmwx0eo4uc2G%2Bk5CTMF8WfWYRMYPHpksM%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=&X-Amz-Signature=2395e814f4d8daa5ae86f9b40b76c16f042757008c595fc1c","https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/link.link2.website.com/link-file/item-file/item_id%3D168cc901-41fe-4994-a5dd-fbcc7bf1d649/date%3D2021-10-01/item-file-test%20%282%29.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATIQ7FVSIUGCQZL7N%2F20220106%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220106T072037Z&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD8zcE7Dk0NBD2F%2Fr9hyTzZop0%2BeJ%2BnQAthpBO3OaGR7AIgI03YGJOTcNzQ79JjZYQvI4HD4A8hKNC5Edq%2FSXiMZTEqugIIoP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjQ0NNpe7sy2dtEb%2BtoeBydBYt%2B5PfH6o1ISCeGe6WfuUaFQZEM0Yl2AUGhGb06S8dTDEsNqOBjqaAadtJx31fGUhIHkaE21M%2BJffVKmz9XXYeGx2MmpllUzCUbD7vEBM%2BKxJs5XQ%2BiZs5sslLFdfjMaWbrFYgUmMLX6fz4HXABR6zFIBH%2FiIvtijgX4dkXHUWssRHZD96Qo2ATHWVhM%2FxW4ut1LkLJt1c9U44L9eofZ2Zwp5vLyEIem6c2Nmwx0eo4uc2G%2Bk5CTMF8WfWYRMYPHpksM%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=&X-Amz-Signature=2395e814f4d8daa5ae86f9b40b76c16f042757008c595fc1c"];

const encoded_filename = input_uri.replace(/^.*\/([^/]+?)\?.*$/, '$1');
const plain_filename = decodeURI(encoded_filename);

console.log(plain_filename);
```

But I get an error saying that `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: input_uri.replace is not a function.` Any idea what's wrong with my code? Any advice would help!

Comment: You need to loop through the array instead of applying RegEx on the array itself

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how that loop would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array to get filename, RegEx is for `strings`

```js
const input_uri = ["https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/link.link2.website.com/link-file/item-file/item_id%3D168cc901-41fe-4994-a5dd-fbcc7bf1d649/date%3D2021-10-01/item-file-test%20%282%29.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATIQ7FVSIUGCQZL7N%2F20220106%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220106T072037Z&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD8zcE7Dk0NBD2F%2Fr9hyTzZop0%2BeJ%2BnQAthpBO3OaGR7AIgI03YGJOTcNzQ79JjZYQvI4HD4A8hKNC5Edq%2FSXiMZTEqugIIoP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjQ0NNpe7sy2dtEb%2BtoeBydBYt%2B5PfH6o1ISCeGe6WfuUaFQZEM0Yl2AUGhGb06S8dTDEsNqOBjqaAadtJx31fGUhIHkaE21M%2BJffVKmz9XXYeGx2MmpllUzCUbD7vEBM%2BKxJs5XQ%2BiZs5sslLFdfjMaWbrFYgUmMLX6fz4HXABR6zFIBH%2FiIvtijgX4dkXHUWssRHZD96Qo2ATHWVhM%2FxW4ut1LkLJt1c9U44L9eofZ2Zwp5vLyEIem6c2Nmwx0eo4uc2G%2Bk5CTMF8WfWYRMYPHpksM%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=&X-Amz-Signature=2395e814f4d8daa5ae86f9b40b76c16f042757008c595fc1c", "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/link.link2.website.com/link-file/item-file/item_id%3D168cc901-41fe-4994-a5dd-fbcc7bf1d649/date%3D2021-10-01/item-file-test%20%282%29.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATIQ7FVSIUGCQZL7N%2F20220106%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220106T072037Z&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD8zcE7Dk0NBD2F%2Fr9hyTzZop0%2BeJ%2BnQAthpBO3OaGR7AIgI03YGJOTcNzQ79JjZYQvI4HD4A8hKNC5Edq%2FSXiMZTEqugIIoP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjQ0NNpe7sy2dtEb%2BtoeBydBYt%2B5PfH6o1ISCeGe6WfuUaFQZEM0Yl2AUGhGb06S8dTDEsNqOBjqaAadtJx31fGUhIHkaE21M%2BJffVKmz9XXYeGx2MmpllUzCUbD7vEBM%2BKxJs5XQ%2BiZs5sslLFdfjMaWbrFYgUmMLX6fz4HXABR6zFIBH%2FiIvtijgX4dkXHUWssRHZD96Qo2ATHWVhM%2FxW4ut1LkLJt1c9U44L9eofZ2Zwp5vLyEIem6c2Nmwx0eo4uc2G%2Bk5CTMF8WfWYRMYPHpksM%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=&X-Amz-Signature=2395e814f4d8daa5ae86f9b40b76c16f042757008c595fc1c", "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/link.link2.website.com/link-file/item-file/item_id%3D168cc901-41fe-4994-a5dd-fbcc7bf1d649/date%3D2021-10-01/item-file-test%20%282%29.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATIQ7FVSIUGCQZL7N%2F20220106%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220106T072037Z&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD8zcE7Dk0NBD2F%2Fr9hyTzZop0%2BeJ%2BnQAthpBO3OaGR7AIgI03YGJOTcNzQ79JjZYQvI4HD4A8hKNC5Edq%2FSXiMZTEqugIIoP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjQ0NNpe7sy2dtEb%2BtoeBydBYt%2B5PfH6o1ISCeGe6WfuUaFQZEM0Yl2AUGhGb06S8dTDEsNqOBjqaAadtJx31fGUhIHkaE21M%2BJffVKmz9XXYeGx2MmpllUzCUbD7vEBM%2BKxJs5XQ%2BiZs5sslLFdfjMaWbrFYgUmMLX6fz4HXABR6zFIBH%2FiIvtijgX4dkXHUWssRHZD96Qo2ATHWVhM%2FxW4ut1LkLJt1c9U44L9eofZ2Zwp5vLyEIem6c2Nmwx0eo4uc2G%2Bk5CTMF8WfWYRMYPHpksM%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=&X-Amz-Signature=2395e814f4d8daa5ae86f9b40b76c16f042757008c595fc1c"];
input_uri.forEach(uri => {
  const encoded_filename = uri.replace(/^.*\/([^/]+?)\?.*$/, '$1');
  const plain_filename = decodeURI(encoded_filename);

  console.log(plain_filename);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

`input_uri` is an array with one string element (because you wrapped it in `[]`s).

`.replace` is a method available on strings themselves, not arrays.

So you'll need to either get rid of the array braces, or do something like `input_uri[0].replace(..` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here ***input_uri*** is an array, not string and ***replace*** is a method available on strings type, not array type.

So you can use `input_uri[0].replace(/^.*\/([^/]+?)\?.*$/, '$1');`

```js
const input_uri = ["https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/link.link2.website.com/link-file/item-file/item_id%3D168cc901-41fe-4994-a5dd-fbcc7bf1d649/date%3D2021-10-01/item-file-test%20%282%29.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATIQ7FVSIUGCQZL7N%2F20220106%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220106T072037Z&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD8zcE7Dk0NBD2F%2Fr9hyTzZop0%2BeJ%2BnQAthpBO3OaGR7AIgI03YGJOTcNzQ79JjZYQvI4HD4A8hKNC5Edq%2FSXiMZTEqugIIoP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjQ0NNpe7sy2dtEb%2BtoeBydBYt%2B5PfH6o1ISCeGe6WfuUaFQZEM0Yl2AUGhGb06S8dTDEsNqOBjqaAadtJx31fGUhIHkaE21M%2BJffVKmz9XXYeGx2MmpllUzCUbD7vEBM%2BKxJs5XQ%2BiZs5sslLFdfjMaWbrFYgUmMLX6fz4HXABR6zFIBH%2FiIvtijgX4dkXHUWssRHZD96Qo2ATHWVhM%2FxW4ut1LkLJt1c9U44L9eofZ2Zwp5vLyEIem6c2Nmwx0eo4uc2G%2Bk5CTMF8WfWYRMYPHpksM%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=&X-Amz-Signature=2395e814f4d8daa5ae86f9b40b76c16f042757008c595fc1c","https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/link.link2.website.com/link-file/item-file/item_id%3D168cc901-41fe-4994-a5dd-fbcc7bf1d649/date%3D2021-10-01/item-file-test%20%282%29.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATIQ7FVSIUGCQZL7N%2F20220106%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220106T072037Z&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD8zcE7Dk0NBD2F%2Fr9hyTzZop0%2BeJ%2BnQAthpBO3OaGR7AIgI03YGJOTcNzQ79JjZYQvI4HD4A8hKNC5Edq%2FSXiMZTEqugIIoP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjQ0NNpe7sy2dtEb%2BtoeBydBYt%2B5PfH6o1ISCeGe6WfuUaFQZEM0Yl2AUGhGb06S8dTDEsNqOBjqaAadtJx31fGUhIHkaE21M%2BJffVKmz9XXYeGx2MmpllUzCUbD7vEBM%2BKxJs5XQ%2BiZs5sslLFdfjMaWbrFYgUmMLX6fz4HXABR6zFIBH%2FiIvtijgX4dkXHUWssRHZD96Qo2ATHWVhM%2FxW4ut1LkLJt1c9U44L9eofZ2Zwp5vLyEIem6c2Nmwx0eo4uc2G%2Bk5CTMF8WfWYRMYPHpksM%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=&X-Amz-Signature=2395e814f4d8daa5ae86f9b40b76c16f042757008c595fc1c","https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/link.link2.website.com/link-file/item-file/item_id%3D168cc901-41fe-4994-a5dd-fbcc7bf1d649/date%3D2021-10-01/item-file-test%20%282%29.xlsx?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATIQ7FVSIUGCQZL7N%2F20220106%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220106T072037Z&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJHMEUCIQD8zcE7Dk0NBD2F%2Fr9hyTzZop0%2BeJ%2BnQAthpBO3OaGR7AIgI03YGJOTcNzQ79JjZYQvI4HD4A8hKNC5Edq%2FSXiMZTEqugIIoP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARADGgwyMjQ0NNpe7sy2dtEb%2BtoeBydBYt%2B5PfH6o1ISCeGe6WfuUaFQZEM0Yl2AUGhGb06S8dTDEsNqOBjqaAadtJx31fGUhIHkaE21M%2BJffVKmz9XXYeGx2MmpllUzCUbD7vEBM%2BKxJs5XQ%2BiZs5sslLFdfjMaWbrFYgUmMLX6fz4HXABR6zFIBH%2FiIvtijgX4dkXHUWssRHZD96Qo2ATHWVhM%2FxW4ut1LkLJt1c9U44L9eofZ2Zwp5vLyEIem6c2Nmwx0eo4uc2G%2Bk5CTMF8WfWYRMYPHpksM%3D&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=&X-Amz-Signature=2395e814f4d8daa5ae86f9b40b76c16f042757008c595fc1c"];

const encoded_filename = input_uri[0].replace(/^.*\/([^/]+?)\?.*$/, '$1');
const plain_filename = decodeURI(encoded_filename);

console.log(plain_filename);
```